# Built-in function to read __slots__

Tags: python, descriptor

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
class Test(object):
    prop = property(lambda self: "property")
```

The descriptor takes priority whenever I try to access `Test().prop`. So that will return `'property'`. If I want to access the object's instance storage, I can do:

```
x = Test()
x.__dict__["prop"] = 12
print(x.__dict__["prop"])
```

However if I change my class to:

```
class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ("prop",)
    prop = property(lambda self: "property")
```

How do I do the same, and access the internal storage of `x`, to write `12` and read it back, since `x.__dict__` no longer exist?

I am fairly new with Python, but I understand the Python philosophy is to give complete control, so why is an implementation detail preventing me from doing that?

Isn't Python missing a built-in function that could read from an instance internal storage, something like:

```
instance_vars(x)["prop"] = 12
print(instance_vars(x)["prop"])
```

which would work like `vars`, except it also works with `__slots__`, and with built-in types that don't have a `__dict__`?

Comment: There's complete control, and there's things that are very silly to do. What do you need this for?

Comment: What are you doing mucking about with `__slots__` anyway? There's almost never a need to do that.

Comment: There are plenty of scenarios where it would make sense to do that. Let's say for instance, that I try to serialize the state of my object.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: that's a good point, why did they include in the language something that isn't useful in the first place?

Comment: `__slots__` is a specialised tool. If you're not sure if you need it, you don't need it.

Comment: My question isn't whether I need it or not. My question is just to clarify my understanding that some language features in Python have deep design problems. BTW, that quote from Tim Peters, was about metaclasses, not `__slots__`.

Comment: The manual tells you why they are included and when they are useful. I don't recall ever needing to use `__slots__`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer, **You can't**

The problem is that slots are themselves implemented in terms of descriptors.  Given:

```
class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ("prop",)

t = Test()
```

the phrase:

```
t.prop
```

Is translated, approximately to:

```
Test.prop.__get__(t, Test)
```

where `Test.prop` is a `<type 'member_descriptor'>` crafted by the run-time specifically to load `prop` values out of `Test` instances from their reserved space.

If you add another descriptor to the class body definition, it masks out the `member_descriptor` that would let you get to the slotted attribute; there's no way to ask for it, it's just not there anymore.  It's effectively like saying:

```
class Test(object):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return self.__dict__['prop']

    @property
    def prop(self):
        return "property"
```

You've defined it twice.  there's no way to "get at" the first `prop` definition.

---

but:

Long answer, **you can't *in a general way.*** You can

You can still abuse the python type system to get at it using another class definition.  You can change the type of a python object, so long as it has the exact same class layout, which roughly means that it has all of the same slots:

```
>>> class Test1(object):
...     __slots__ = ["prop"]
...     prop = property(lambda self: "property")
... 
>>> class Test2(object):
...     __slots__ = ["prop"]
... 
>>> t = Test1()
>>> t.prop
'property'
>>> t.__class__ = Test2
>>> t.prop = 5
>>> t.prop
5
>>> t.__class__ = Test1
>>> t.prop
'property'
```

But there's no general way to introspect an instance to work out its class layout; you just have to know from context.  You could look at it's `__slots__` class attribute, but that won't tell you about the slots provided in the superclass (if any) nor will it give you any hint if that attribute has *changed* for some reason after the class was defined.

Comment: I hope never to see it in production.  I've half a mind to remove it just to keep anyone from getting ideas.

Comment: I'm not insterested about the hack. What I like in this answer is: 1: __You can't__, 2: the explanation about the `<type 'member_descriptor'>` pointing to a reserved space that __you can't access in Python__ without the help of the descriptor.

Comment: Except, you *can* access it; but only through the descriptor the run-time hands you.  If you've thrown it out, that's your error.

Comment: seems I need a sarcasm sign. but yes, nice explanation that this has nothing to do with `__slots__`, and the "problem" is that you are shadowing the name. which -in a way- is the purpose of properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what and why you want to do this, but does this help you?

```
>>> class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ("prop",)
    prop = property(lambda self: "property")


>>> a = Test()
>>> b = Test()
>>> a.prop
'property'
>>> tmp = Test.prop
>>> Test.prop = 23
>>> a.prop
23
>>> Test.prop = tmp; del tmp
>>> b.prop
'property'
```

of course, you cannot overwrite the property on a per-instance basis, that's the whole point of slotted descriptors.

Note that subclasses of a class with `__slots__` do have a `__dict__` unless you manually define `__slots__`, so you can do:

```
>>> class Test2(Test):pass

>>> t = Test2()
>>> t.prop
'property'
>>> t.__dict__['prop'] = 5
>>> t.__dict__['prop']
5
>>> Test2.prop
<property object at 0x00000000032C4278>
```

but still:

```
>>> t.prop
'property'
```

and that's not because of `__slots__`, it's the way descriptors work.

your `__dict__` is bypassed on attribute lookup, you are just abusing it as data structure that happens to be there for storing a state.
it is equivalent to do this:

```
>>> class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ("prop", "state")
    prop = property(lambda self: "property")
    state = {"prop": prop}


>>> t.prop
'property'
>>> t.state["prop"] = 5
>>> t.state["prop"]
5
>>> t.prop
'property'
```

Comment: My question was about per-instance basis. All of this is for educational pupose.

Comment: The problem is that there is a single semantic to make a "property access" (going through the class/descriptors), and make an "instance attribute access".

Comment: @Flavien that is not a problem, that is what makes it unneccessary in python to write getter/setter for every public atribute. And I'm very glad we got that :)

Comment: This is a strength, but a weakness at the same time. Your objects have data that you just can't access at will in some situations. I think this is just bad language design, as there are surely ways to have both at the same time (see C# properties). Like I said in my question, all it would take is a built-in function able to read from that reserved space directly. Why do we have `__dict__` to read in some cases and nothing when `__slots__` is used? This is just inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

If you really ever want to do something like that, and you REALL REALLY need something like that, you can always override `__getattribute__` and `__setattribute__`, it's just as stupid... This is just to prove it to you:

```
class Test(object):
    __slots__ = ("prop",)
    prop = property(lambda self: "property")
    __internal__ = {}

    def __getattribute__(self, k):
        if k == "__dict__":
            return self.__internal__
        else:
            try:
                return object.__getattribute__(self, k)
            except AttributeError, e:
                try:
                    return self.__internal__[k]
                except KeyError:
                    raise e

    def __setattribute__(self, k, v):
        self.__internal__[k] = v
        object.__setattribute__(self, k, v)

t = Test()

print t.prop

t.__dict__["prop"] = "test"
print "from dict", t.__dict__["prop"]
print "from getattr", t.prop

import traceback
# These won't work: raise AttributeError
try:
    t.prop2 = "something"
except AttributeError:
    print "see? I told you!"
    traceback.print_exc()

try:
    print t.prop2
except AttributeError:
    print "Haha! Again!"
    traceback.print_exc()
```

(Tried it on Python 2.7)
It's exactly what you expect I guess. Don't do this, it's useless.

Comment: Sure, but this is a hack. Here you end up having a dictionary in your class, which makes using `__slots__` pointless, and you have no guarantee that what's in `__internal__` reflects accurately what's in the slots (as you can easily change the content of `__internal__` from the outside).

Comment: Of course it's a hack, but don't say you don't have complete control. It's a hack for a hacky situation. You can also as easily change the content of `__dict__` from the outside. And you could add a check to verify that what's in `__internal__` is always in `__slots__`... Once you override `__setattribute__`, `__slots__` has no meaning anymore...

Comment: @Flavien sure, but your arguments also apply to your `__dict__` "solution". I think you have to read up on how properties are implemented.